User input of single characters working properly during debugging but not in runtime
I am currently making a program that reads input from the user and stores it in a file. When the user inputs some character, it should show up in the terminal however, during runtime, the program waits until the key "enter" is inputted to show the text that had been written on the current line. In contrast, when debugging, everything runs as intended. Why does this happen?
This is the code:
import os
from msvcrt import getch

def get():
    string = str(getch())
    string = string.replace("'", "", 2)
    string = string.replace("b", "", 1)
    return string

def addEn():
    os.system("cls")
    lineDict = {}
    line = ""
    lastLine = 0

    print("SYNTAX: word - дума")
    print("Input '|' to stop")
    print("---------------------")

    f = open('test.txt', mode = "w")

    f.write("\n")
    inp = get()
    print("0. ", end = "")
    while inp != "|":
        if inp != "\\r":
            line = line + inp

            print(inp, end = "")
            f.write(inp)
        elif inp == "\\r":
            lastLine = lastLine+1

            print("\n", end="")
            f.write("\n")

            print(f"{lastLine}. ", end="")
            lineDict[lastLine-1] = line

            line = ""
        inp = get()
        
    f.close()

    print("\nPress any key to go back. . .")
    getch()

addEn()

Note: The code is still unfinished, so there will be mistakes (besides the one I am writing about)

What exactly are you referring to by "when debugging"?

@mkrieger1 using the python debugger to debug my code

In your case do you need to read the input real time? Normaly we should  press enter to capture the input right?

@MalithDilshan This is exactly why I've used getch() - a character needs to be immediately read and printed without the need of pressing enter

Alright getch will only work in windows systems. If you are using unix based system then you need to Use termios and tty modules to capture the inputs.

@MalithDilshan I'm on Windows

Are you running the debugger in the same terminal window as the application? They're both trying to read from the terminal, one in line-by-line mode, the other in single-character, and this gets messy.

@Barmar No, they both run in two different terminals.

For anyone who has the same confusing problem in the future: the buffer needs to be flushed as the \n character is not printed. It needs to be either done manually by adding sys.stdout.flush() after every print function that has a parameter end without a new line in the string given or by just adding flush to print() and setting it to TRUE.
Here is a post that explains it better than me:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sys-stdout-flush/
